# Boost with Borland C++ Builder

Tags: boost, c++builder, c++builder-6

Has anybody used the Boost library in Borland C++ Builder? Is there any online resource of building it and using it in Borland C++ Builder?
The boost documentation is very brief about the specific task.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which version of C++ Builder? The recent ones like XE and XE2 include Boost, and there are some Borland-specific statements in the Boost headers.

Comment: C++Builder 2010 also includes quite a lot of Boost. Not all of the Boost functions work, but most do. I find them very helpful and use many of them in almost all of my apps.

Comment: C++ Builder Xe and XE2 went a bit downhill for boost support, but lots of functionality still works.

Answer (score 2):

I've compiled boost 1.33 for borland c++ builder 6 by next steps:

1. First, I've downloaded and extracted the
   boost-jam-3.1.18-1-ntx86;
2. Downloaded and extracted  boost library 1.33
3. Copied bjam.exe to the extracted boost root folder;
4. Run bjam with: `bjam -sTOOLS=borland stage`;

Most of the components were compiled.

Answer (score 0):

XE and XE2 come with Boost 1.39.  Most, but not all, of the header only libraries work.

Compiling a newer boost would be quite an exercise I think.